# How do i get the week number of the last 4 weeks C#

Tags: c#, date, week-number

I have this two methods:

```
private string CreateWeekPivotTable(string TemporaryTable, DateTime StartDate)
{
    string pivotTable = "Select TT.Description, TT.Name, TT.Code, \n";
    int countday = 7;

    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(-1 * (7 * 4));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       string week = $"Ifnull(SUM(case when  TT.DateSale = '{DateFormat(StartDate.AddDays(countday), 
     OptionsPeriodEnum.YEAR)}' And TT.Week ='{WeekNumber(StartDate.AddDays(countday)).ToString("D" +2)}' 
        then TT.Quantity  else 0 end), 0.0) as 'Week{(i + 1).ToString("D" + 2)}', \n ";

        pivotTable += week;
        countday += 7;
    }

    pivotTable = pivotTable + " '' as Empty \n from TemporaryTable TT \n group by 
                 TT.Description,TT.Name,TT.Code";
    return $"{TemporaryTable} {pivotTable}";
}

private int WeekNumber(DateTime Date)
{
    return CultureInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

which give me the next output:

```
Ifnull(SUM(case when  TT.DateSale = '2019' And TT.Week ='53' then TT.Quantity  else 0 end), 0.0) as 'Week01',  
Ifnull(SUM(case when  TT.DateSale = '2020' And TT.Week ='02' then TT.Quantity  else 0 end), 0.0) as 'Week02', 
Ifnull(SUM(case when  TT.DateSale = '2020' And TT.Week ='03' then TT.Quantity  else 0 end), 0.0) as 'Week03', 
Ifnull(SUM(case when  TT.DateSale = '2020' And TT.Week ='04' then TT.Quantity  else 0 end), 0.0) as 'Week04'
```

The problem is, it's not including week 01 from 2020.
How can i solve this?

Comment: TT.Week = TT.Week % 52 / TT.DateSale += TT.Week / 52

Comment: Sorry, how do i replace this in my code? I'm getting an error in the resulting query

Comment: **EDIT:** I figured the way to execute my query without errors, but now my output result is 0

Comment: Then you need to use 'if ( value % 52 > 0 )'